# Select statement with Where clause only if some values equals to something

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna make a select statement with a where clause that only is used if some value isn't equal to something.
So for example i execute this, but only if value equals is not equals to "maybe".

```
SELECT * FROM * WHERE value = 'correct '
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually in SQL you use '<>' to indicate that the column value is not equal to a parameter value.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value <> 'maybe'
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed tablename in query (may be typomistake..

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value = 'correct ' and value!= 'incorrect';
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value IN ( 'correct ', 'something');
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value NOT IN ( 'incorrect ', 'something');
```

EDIT

```
  SELECT * FROM (    (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value != 'incorrect') UNION  (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value= 'correct'))  tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL logic would apparently be:

```
WHERE value <> 'maybe'
```

However, if `value` can have `NULL` values, this also filters out `NULL` values.  So you can use the `NULL`-safe comparison operator:

```
WHERE NOT (value <=> 'maybe')
```